# How can I run Dart code from the android part(Kotlin code) of my project?[FLUTTER]

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, background-service

I have been trying to work on an app where I have a background service that runs in my flutter project. This service runs from the android part of the project. I want to be able to run dart code from the android part of my project since some functionality is present only with the dart framework(ie. sending data to firebase).

My exact question is : How can I run dart code from the Kotlin part of my flutter project?

It would be extremely helpful if you can help me on this
Thanks!!!

Comment: @loloof64 I have seen that you had a similar doubt. Would you be able to help me on this? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @Morrison Chang could you tell me as to how I can initialise methodChannel in Kotlin?